# How can I stop Microsoft SharePoint keeps adding itself to my Login Items

Tags: finder, login-items, microsoft-sharepoint

My office uses a software suite created by an independent developer called Microsoft.

An app within this suite keeps adding itself to my Ventura 13 startup items. I neither asked for nor approved this system-level change on my Mac.

I previously solved this with another app in the same suite by opening the app, then changing some settings in the applications preferences; however, this "SharePoint" app can not be found in the apps folder or by using the Spotlight search tool on the Mac. Additionally, I can not see that the app has ever started, disallowing me to access it as an open app.

Apple usually does a very good job of controlling renegade developers like this—at least offering tools to allow users like us to exercise our choice—but this one has me confounded.

**Does anyone know how to prevent the addition of Microsoft SharePoint to our LogIn items?**

Comment: "...independent developer called Microsoft." lol - I found in this [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-gets-added-automatically-to-my-login/ecd186a5-271c-4ccc-a7d7-ff96f1d24511) posting that Sharepoint is an app within the OneDrive app (OneDrive > Contents ...). See Paul_065's comment. Apparently, you aren't the only one who finds this unnecessary. There seems no way around it being added to Login Items.

Comment: Excellent @IconDaemon . You got one step farther than me in figuring this out. From what I can see on that thread is that no one has found a way to stop this company from actively annoying users and doing what probably violates the Apple Developer's agreement. Who do they think they are?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's SharePoint app is contained within the OneDrive app's container, and is loaded into Login Items without the expected user control or authorization. Whether or not this violates Apple's Developer agreement is beyond the scope of this answer.

There are several ways one can attempt to control this behavior. I have not tried any of these methods because, fortunately, I do not need to use OneDrive nor SharePoint.

1. Delete the SharePoint app from within OneDrive app container and replace it with an identically named file (perhaps a text file) and then lock the file from modification with the Finder's Get Info GUI.
2. Remove the ability for the SharePoint app to be executed by using the Terminal command `chmod` and remove the execute flag.
3. Execute `chflags uchg` on the SharePoint app. You may need root or superuser access.

Note: executing any of the previous commands on preventing SharePoint from loading into Login Items may break OneDrive, or prevent OneDrive from being updated. *Experiment at your own risk.*

Lastly, just live with it in Login Items and move on.

You could also email Bill Gates here: bill.gates@gatesfoundation.org

Comment: Thanks @IconDaemon for assembling these strategies. I will attempt them on Monday and update you with my progress (or notify you of our success). N.B.: Attempts to contact gatesfoundation.org representatives have as yet gone unanswered. These companies seem entirely unrelated. Are you sure this is the customer service contact?

Comment:  • Bill Gates _never_ picks up the phone. His voicemail box has been full for many years.

Comment: I tried all of these methods (using a controlled experiment methodology), plus a few more permutations of the file permissions. In every case, altering _any_ aspect of the file resulted in an error message upon startup, and the failure of OneDrive to start: "OneDrive can't start//There's a problem with the application files. Please download the application on this computer and try again." I didn't realise that this Gates was the dev hisself: That's pretty typical behaviour from that sort. I will notify our large institution's IT of the potential privacy leak. Not much else to do.

Comment: My comments about Gates were a joke, Parapluie. He's the founder of Microsoft and no longer has direct dealings with the company, being a multi-billionaire with hundreds of minions to run the company. I hope you figure this out this problem, but sometimes, the only option is to throw up your hands and move on.